# having tow panels that steak together using bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I wanted to create a panel(if its a panel) like [image]

I tried making it using this code :

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-body">
                <div class="row">

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-body">
                <div class="row">

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

it makes two panels but there is gap between them.
how should i approach to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I made a plunkr to simulate the example. [exmaple](https://plnkr.co/edit/STrTZtsFY4d0Tw5cj2h2?p=preview)

Basically i add a css who make the rtl. 
[bootstrap-rtl](https://github.com/morteza/bootstrap-rtl)

and the code for the html is this . hope it helps.

```
<body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">
          <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-body">
              <form>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email address</label>
                  <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" placeholder="Email">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Password</label>
                  <input type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Password">
                </div>

                <div class="checkbox">
                  <label>
                    <input type="checkbox"> Check me out
                  </label>
                </div>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
              </form>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-body">
              Basic panel example
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /container -->
  </body>
```